# How to embed a video file from Strapi Media Library into CKEditor5 custom field?

Tags: video, ckeditor, media, strapi, ckeditor5

In Strapi we have an option to upload a video file, but there is no option for embedding those files in rich text editors like CKEditor5?

I've tried all the available plugins from Strapi Plugins Market. TINYMCE has such an option, but it's not fully free to use (only 1000 request per month). HTML5Editor is outdated. CKEditor5 seems like a really good free to use editor, but I guess it doesn't have such an option yet?

Comment: You may try this [CKEditor plugin](https://market.strapi.io/plugins/@_sh-strapi-plugin-ckeditor)